# R: Interpretation of caret train output

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a pretty basic question about cross-validated hyper-parameter search  in `caret` using the `train` function. While running, it produces output that looks like this:

[image]

My question is why are there more than one row per hyperparameter configuration, and what do the `+` and `-` in the output signify?

---

Some sample code that can produce output like the above (random example taken from [here](http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/12/caret-package-stop-solution-building-predictive-models/)):

```
library(caret)
library(datasets)
data(mtcars)
split = createDataPartition(y = mtcars$mpg, p = 0.6, list = FALSE)
dev = mtcars[split,]
val = mtcars[-split,]
ctrl = trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10, verbose = TRUE)
lmCVFit = train(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, method = "lm", trControl = ctrl, metric="Rsquared")
summary(lmCVFit)
```

Comment: @LyzandeR It doesn't matter, the output is the same for all calls to `train` with `verbose = TRUE`. Some sample code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to be specific in the explanation that's why I asked for the actual code, but here it goes.

The output shows you the parameters tested in each fold of the 10-fold cross validation. In more detail:

Your second row (I start from the second because the testing starts with a + and you ll understand why) shows that in Fold 3 the parameters tested were:

- `eta = 0.01, max_depth=4, gamma=1 and nround=1000`

The algorithm will actually keep those stored because it is trying to find the best combination of the parameters. In the next row (row number 3) the output is exactly the same as row 2 with the only difference that it starts with a minus sign. This is just to notify you that processing of the above parameters has now ended. You will notice that all rows starting with a minus sign are always the same as the rows above them (that have a plus sign). Row number 4 starts with a plus sign and tests a new set of parameters (actually the only thing changed is the max_depth=8 this time). This process is still in the 3rd fold of cross validation though and this will happen the same number of times in the other folds, so that the algorithm can choose the optimal parameters.

Comment: So just markers to indicate start and end of training for a particular hyper-parameter configuration? Can you point out the exact lines of code on Github that produce this output so that I can be sure?

Comment: @fgnu I know this from experience (look at your output and you will see that the lines are always the same between +s and -s) and I have discussed this with my colleagues, too. It is also the standard way of output in R. `stepAIC` is does the same. I don't have the time to look on github and find the exact lines that produce this. That would probably require a lot of investigation which I cannot do right now.

Comment: @fgnu You could start from [this](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/createFolds.R) one. Check line 54. But the printing happens in the `traindefault.r` file.

Comment: No worries. I think that your request forced me to create an easily (and quickly) debugged example. The output is raised by `progress` on lines 30 & 236, called by `nominalTrainWorkflow` called by `train.default`.

Comment: @fgnu aah great. Thanks for sharing. I ll have a look at that too at some point.

Comment: As ` fg nu` states, the code that generates it is [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/workflows.R), The function `nominalTrainWorkflow` is usually where it occurs (depending on the type of resampling etc) around lines 74 and 321 (in a function called `progress`).

Comment: Thanks @topepo . Very nice package :)